# Comparing values to natural numbers in C++

Tags: c++, loops

I'm examining trades.  I want to reject trades when their price is not a multiple of a tick size, or within a given tolerance of the multiple.

i.e. if an order in submitted with a price P and abs(P - N*tick_size) > tolerance for all natural numbers, such an order would be rejected because the price is invalid.

How would I test this against all numbers?  Any tips would be helpful!

Comment: What is your actual problem? `abs(P - N*tick_size) > tolerance` seems like the canonical way to do this?

Comment: Use fixed-point arithmetic. There's bound to be a smallest possible tick size; express everything in multiples of that.

Comment: @dionadar Tick size, tolerance and price are known.  We just want to find if there such an N exists so that abs(P - N*tick_size) <= tolerance

Comment: What about dividing P by tick_size?

Comment: Yes, I think that's a good idea, but I don't know how to actually construct a loop that would iterate through all the natural numbers?

Comment: @KerrekSB I know the tick size already.  It's just a matter of testing whether an N exists.

Comment: As I said, use fixed point, integral arithmetic and you don't need any inequalities or abses. Just a simple remainder operation should do the trick.

Comment: If by "all natural numbers" you mean all natural numbers from -inf to +inf, then you are in trouble. Given to limitations in our technology, in a computer the "naturals" numbers are limited usually between -2^31+1 and 2^31-1.

Answer (score 3):

No loop is needed. This can be seen easily: |P - N*s| < t implies that |P/s - N| < t (let s be positive...)

Therefore, to compute your N, you need to find the nearest integer to P/s. Or, N = [round](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round)(P/s).

This leads to a simple algorithm:

```
auto const N = round(P/tick_size);
bool const result = abs(P - N*tick_size) > tolerance
```

Note, that I cheated a bit, by assuming that your numbers are reals. However, for fixed-point or integer math this is almost the same, since an integer division is always rounded towards zero. We can further simplify by performing the `abs` first:

```
auto const Pp = abs(P);
auto const N1 = P / tick_size;
auto const N2 = N1 + 1;
bool const result = !(abs(Pp - N1*tick_size) <= tolerance || abs(Pp - N2*tick_size) <= tolerance);
```

#### Hints on the arithmetic to use

As @KerrekSB already pointed out, you should always do serious financial math as fixed-point math.

If you really need all natural numbers, you also have to look at arbitrary precision integer math for your underlying primitives. The [GNU Multiprecision Math Library](https://gmplib.org/) is a great solution if you are working on Linux.